# difference before and after trigger in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Can somebody explain difference between "before" and "after" trigger in oracle 10g with an example ?

Comment: I still wasn't sure what you were looking for in terms of simplicity, so I deleted my answer.  Someone else may have a good idea.

Comment: For every small doubt i am posting a question in stack overflow without thinking .....(i think i should not do).... I understood the triggers concept now.Hence forth i'll think before posting the question...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First, I'll start my answer by defining **trigger**: a **trigger** is an stored procedure that is run when a row is added, modified or deleted.

Triggers can run *BEFORE* the action is taken or *AFTER* the action is taken.

`BEFORE` triggers are usually used when validation needs to take place before accepting the change. They run before any change is made to the database. Let's say you run a database for a bank. You have a table `accounts` and a table `transactions`. If a user makes a withdrawal from his account, you would want to make sure that the user has enough credits in his account for his withdrawal. The `BEFORE` trigger will allow to do that and prevent the row from being inserted in `transactions` if the balance in `accounts` is not enough.

`AFTER` triggers are usually used when information needs to be updated in a separate table due to a change. They run after changes have been made to the database (not necessarily committed). Let's go back to our back example. After a successful transaction, you would want `balance` to be updated in the `accounts` table. An `AFTER` trigger will allow you to do exactly that.

Comment: +1 I would just add that some trigger validations have to be performed in AFTER row triggers, because it is only in AFTER triggers that the column values are "fixed".  In a BEFORE trigger you could validate and pass some complex rule based on the value of :NEW.col only for the value of :NEW.col to be changed later in the trigger such that the rule is now violated.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not completely sure what you're interested in knowing, so I'll keep this fundamental.

Before Triggers

- As per the name, these triggers are fired prior to creating the row in the table. Subsequently, since the row has not yet been created you have full access to the :new.table_element field. This allows for data cleansing and uniformity if unwanted/malformed data is attempting to be inserted/updated. This is just a basic example, but you need to utilize the before trigger any time you may require access to the ":new" data.

After Triggers

- Since the after trigger fires once the row has already been created, these triggers are typically utilized when you want logic to occur due to the row. For example, if you have an address table and a user updates his/her address, then you may want to update the address reference ids in an xref table upon creation (if you happen to be retaining all old addresses as well). Also, unlike the before trigger, you do not have access to modify any of the column values since the row already exists in the table.

Answer (score 1):

BEFORE TRIGGER are used when the trigger action should determine whether or not the triggering statements should be allowed to complete .by using BEFORE TRIGGERS user can eliminate unnecessary processing of the triggering statement
but,AFTER TRIGGERS are used when the triggering statements should completed before executing the trigger action.

Comment: Please edit your existing answer, rather than duplicating another.