# Oracle - When does the trigger after insert run?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table in my Oracle database. The table is used as a messaging queue. Sender process writes to it and the receiver process reads from it. I want to update the inserted messages under certain conditions before receiver reads it. If I set a trigger to "UPDATE ROW AFTER INSERT", when exactly will Oracle run it? Will Oracle handle the trigger as the first thing after insert? To be clear, will Oracle run the trigger before the receiver reads the inserted message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the data to be inserted in a before row trigger. See for an explanation of the difference of before and after triggers this question:

[difference before and after trigger in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646110/difference-before-and-after-trigger-in-oracle)

The reader will only be able to see any data after the sender process has committed the changes.