# PL/SQL trigger does not change value of table attribute

Tags: plsql, triggers, aggregate-functions

this is a follow up question from my previous post: 
[PL/SQL Triggers with aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103180/pl-sql-triggers-with-aggregate-function)

I have a trigger named `updategpa` that updates the gpa inside the `student` table whenever grades get changed in the `course` table.

This trigger gets called as a result of 'updateGrades' trigger that updates the `course` table when `assignments` table receives new data.

**Problem: gpa is `0` before and after the trigger is called?**

Could anyone say what is wrong with my trigger?

```
drop table courses;
drop table student;
drop table assignments;

create table student (sid integer, sname char(10), saddress char(10), gpa integer);
create table courses (sid integer, cid integer, cgrade integer);
create table assignments ( sid integer, cid integer, aid integer, agrade integer);

insert into student (sid, sname, saddress, gpa) values (1, 'Mike', 'Brighton', 0);
insert into courses (sid, cid, cgrade) values(1, 2000, 0);

insert into assignments values(1, 2000, 1, 70);
insert into assignments values(1, 2000, 2, 80);

create or replace trigger updateGrades before insert or update or delete of agrade on assignments for each row
    begin
      if inserting then
          update courses set cgrade = :new.agrade where cid = :new.cid and sid = :new.sid;
      elsif updating then
          update courses set cgrade = :old.agrade + (:new.agrade - :old.agrade)
            where cid = :new.cid and sid = :new.sid;
      elsif deleting then
          delete from courses where cid = :new.cid and sid = :new.sid;
      end if;
    end;
/
show errors;

create or replace trigger updategpa after insert or update or delete of cgrade on courses for each row
    begin
        if inserting then
            update student set gpa =
              (select avg(cgrade) from courses inner join student on courses.sid = student.sid
              )
              where sid = 1;
        elsif inserting then
            update student set gpa =
              (select avg(cgrade) from courses inner join student on courses.sid = student.sid
              )
              where sid = 1;
        elsif deleting then
            delete from student where sid = :new.sid;
        end if;
    end;
/
show errors;

select * from courses;
select * from student;
select * from assignments;

update assignments set agrade = agrade + 5;

select * from courses;
select * from student;
select * from assignments;
```

console output:

```
SQL> select * from student;

       SID SNAME      SADDRESS          GPA
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Mike       Brighton            0

SQL> select * from assignments;

       SID        CID        AID     AGRADE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2000          1         70
         1       2000          2         80

SQL>
SQL> update assignments set agrade = agrade + 5;

2 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> select * from courses;

       SID        CID     CGRADE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2000         85

SQL> select * from student;

       SID SNAME      SADDRESS          GPA
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Mike       Brighton            0

SQL> select * from assignments;

       SID        CID        AID     AGRADE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2000          1         75
         1       2000          2         85
```

Comment: You are showing us a trigger on the table `COURSES`, but your update statement is for the `ASSIGNMENTS` table. you have to insert/update/delete into the table defined by the trigger or it won't do anything. Either your entire trigger is built on the wrong table, or your update is touching the wrong table.

Comment: the update for `assignments` is just for me to see what happened in that table. The statements I am looking at are the `select * from student` and `select * from courses`. As you can see, the `gpa` in the `student` table does not change after `5` has been added to `agrade`

Comment: But you never do an insert, update, or delete from `courses` after creating the trigger. It can't have ever fired, so no changes would be observed.

Comment: I apologize, I added the trigger that inserts on `courses` which was part of the previous question. I should have added that from the start but didn't think  of it. It should make more sense now.

Comment: This does help, thank you. Looking more closely now, the reason this isn't firing as expected is because you have two conditions for `INSERTING` and none for `UPDATING`. However, even after fixing that you will have an issue with mutating triggers. Instead of joining to `courses` in your queries, it should really use the `:new.sid` like you do in the `DELETING` section.

Comment: If you really do want to update every GPA on every insert and update (which doesn't seem as likely), then what you want to do is use a statement-level trigger by omitting the `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: so what I did was I declared a variable called `foundAvg' which I assigned to my `select` query.

`declare foundAvg int' , 
   'set foundAvg = (select avg(cgrade) from courses)`. Then what I did was use it in my insert like so ` if inserting then` `insert into student (sid, sname, saddress, gpa)`` values (:new.sid, :new.sname, :new.saddresss, foundAvg)`. I have a feeling I am on the right track but then again I have lots of errors after doing this. Is this the correct approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is your `updategpa` trigger needs to track every change to COURSES at the row level, then aggregate those changes to maintain a running total for each student. This is a good use case for a compound trigger. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005).

```
create or replace trigger updategpa  
for update or update or insert on courses compound trigger   

  type cid_nt is table of courses%rowtype;  
  upd_recs cid_nt;  

  before statement is   
  begin  
    upd_recs := cid_nt();  
  end before statement;  

  before each row is   
  begin  
    upd_recs.extend();  
    if inserting or updating then   
        upd_recs(upd_recs.count()).sid := :new.sid;  
    else  
        upd_recs(upd_recs.count()).sid := :old.sid;  
    end if;  
  end before each row;  

  after each row is   
  begin  
    null;  
  end after each row;  

  after statement is   
  begin  
    for idx in 1 .. upd_recs.count() loop  
      update student   
      set gpa = (select avg(cgrade)  
                 from courses   
                 where courses.sid = student.sid )  
         where sid = upd_recs(idx).sid;  
    end loop;    
  end after statement;  

end;
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gdd99cqwc04g35ejjv3iw5tki) (free OTN account required).